# bootstrap 3 box-sizing not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I thought bootstrap 3 used `box-sizing:border-box` so when I tried to add a margin class to the 2 box-sizing:border-box they stack on top of each other instead of sitting next to each other from sm upwards in size.

```
   <div class="blueBox col-sm-6">
            <input type="checkbox">foo</input>
        </div>
        <div class="blueBox col-sm-6" >
            <input type="checkbox">boo</input>
        </div>
```

css

```
.blueBox {
  background-color: #26a8e0;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `box-sizing : border-box;` property doesn't include margin in the size of the elements. It includes border width and paddding. That is why they don't stay inline.

> **border-box** 
>  
>   The width and height properties include the padding and
>   border, but not the margin.[...]

source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Values)

To simulate margin, you can use border with the same colour as the background :

```
.blueBox {
  background-color: #26a8e0;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  border: 20px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I see, so how would you get my 2 boxes to have that nice margin in between them and still be responsive at xs size?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper is the background a plain colour? Because you could use border instead of margin and give the border `20px` width and the same colour as the background.

Comment: ok thanks I basically want to have 2 big blue boxes with some white space around them.