# Create a margin between two columns without effecting grid layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the body of my page I have split the 12 columns into a body which is 8 columns wide and a sidebar which is 4 columns wide. These two areas are a different colour to the background, so I want them to appear as if they are on top of the background. The problem is that when I set a margin between the two areas in order to make them appear as 2 separate areas it effects the layout of my website as now we have 8 columns, 4 columns and this margin, so the sidebar is pushed below the content. How do you add in a margin like this to separate the two areas without destroying bootstrap's grid layout?

edit: I know I could just nest them and essentially add in a column between the two areas, but I only want a margin of say 15px between the two areas.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content" class="main-content-inner col-sm-12 col-md-8 bg">
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.bg {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.sidebar {
    padding-top: 40px;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: do you have a code example and a jsfiddle with the problem?

Comment: It is pertty hard to answer without code. First guess would be to use borders with the same colour as your background. As bootstraps use `box-sizing:border-box;` it shouldn't ruin your layout. For a better answser share your HTML and CSS. More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971373/bootstrap-3-box-sizing-not-working

Comment: @Stefan I added an example, so I basically want a 15 pixel gap between these 2 divs. You can ignore the poor and messy markup

Comment: @web-tiki I saw this post, but I only want a gap on the left of the div, I don't really want to apply this border around the entire div.

Comment: @germainelol you can just add border to the right or left, you don't have to add it all around example : `border-right: 15px solid #fff;`

Comment: @web-tiki So how would I make it transparent? That's what I would need it to be as my background is a pattern itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width of the sidebar and add a margin-left to it :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/parpp3tu/)**

```
.bg {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height:150px;
}

.sidebar {
    padding-top: 40px;
    width:31%;
    margin-left:2.3333%;
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I end up with just the plain white colour again. The class of `bg` above is set to have a background colour of white, so it's almost as if it isn't applying the border when it's transparent. I know the border is there as it shows up if I use black for example.

Comment: @germainelol Please share code that reproduces your issue in a fiddle would be great because I'm having a hard time understanding your issue and why it occurs.

Comment: I added the CSS, there's nothing else there really, just the default bootstrap code.

Comment: Thanks, that'll do the trick for now. Is that a good way to go about this? It seems a bit of a messy solution

Comment: @germainelol you will just need to adjust width and margin on bootsraps breakpoints with media queries so that the layout doesn't break in responsive design.

Comment: Yeah, I just removed the margin below 992 I think it was, as that was when the layout began to move in accordance with the bootstrap CSS file. Does the job anyway! Thanks